# Проверка на число которое вписывается в массив С++

Tags: c++

Всем привет,есть цикл которые заполняет массив, которые с динамической памятью

```
for (int i = 0; i <= gran-1; i++)
        {   
                cin >> ptr[i];  
        }
```

Как сделать проверку, допустим если число в консоли больше 31 не записывать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считать число, если оно больше - не записывать.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= gran-1; i++)
{   
    cin >> ptr[i];  
    if (ptr[i] > 31) { i--; cout << "Bad input\n"; continue; }
}
```

Чтоб цикл крутился дальше с правильным счетчиком, мы его уменьшаем. И новый цикл опять будет писать в старое значение `i`.

Comment: Может лучше while тогда? Чтобы не дергать туда сюда переменную.

Comment: да, такой вариант лучше, мне кажется/ for(int i=0;i<gran;i++){ while(cin>>ptr[i]){ if (i>31) break;}}

Comment: @pavel Конечно, можно. Я просто указал примерный принцип - проверку введенного значения и откат/повтор.